# Why is the bot on Heroku Server not responding?

Tags: heroku, telegram, python-telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I programmed a simple bot that is connected to Google Sheets API. It asks a few questions to the user and stores it in the Sheet I have. When I use bot.polling it works fine, but I was trying the webhook so I could use Heroku to have my bot running 24/7.

I introduced the code:

```
@server.route('/' + token, methods=['POST'])
def getMessage():
    bot.process_new_updates([telebot.types.Update.de_json(request.stream.read().decode("utf-8"))])
    return "!", 200

@server.route("/")
def webhook():
    bot.remove_webhook()
    bot.set_webhook(url = '<Heroku App Link>' + token)
    return "!", 200

if __name__ == "__main__":
    server.run(host="0.0.0.0", port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000)))
```

I have the `requirements.txt` file and the `Procfile` that currently is like this:

```
web: python3 bot.py
```

I tried a bunch of things in the `Procfile` but this is the only one that didn't gave an error.

When I saw the log this is what I got:

```
2019-09-24T10:18:54.369238+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-09-24T10:19:04.416777+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python3 bot.py`
2019-09-24T10:19:09.868915+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2019-09-24T10:19:09.790773+00:00 app[web.1]: * Serving Flask app "bot" (lazy loading)
2019-09-24T10:19:09.790800+00:00 app[web.1]: * Environment: production
2019-09-24T10:19:09.790853+00:00 app[web.1]: WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
2019-09-24T10:19:09.790940+00:00 app[web.1]: Use a production WSGI server instead.
2019-09-24T10:19:09.790991+00:00 app[web.1]: * Debug mode: off
2019-09-24T10:19:09.799470+00:00 app[web.1]: * Running on http://0.0.0.0:57826/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
2019-09-24T10:19:15.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
```

Can anyone help me understand why the bot doesn't answer any commands?

Comment: This is probably just a typo, but your dependency file should be called `requirements.txt`, not `Requirements.txt`. Anyway, it looks like your bot is running. How are you trying to interact with it?

Comment: It is `requirements.txt` sorry... I send /start or /help that are commands that the bot recognizes with bot.polling()...

Comment: Okay, but how are you trying to connect to the bot? You must point at it somehow, right?

Comment: I thought this was enough for the bot to answer commands and run properly... Maybe not...